# Create multiple variables in a dataframe in R within a loop

Tags: r, loops, indexing

I would like to know what is the best way to create variables within a loop in R using dplyr package, in an existing dataframe. In a first time, I would like to do something like:

```
for i in (1:30){

df <- df %>% mutate(paste0("myvar",i),0) 

}
```

And then something like :

```
for i in (1:30){

df <- df %>%
mutate(paste0("myvar",i)=ifelse(paste0("myvar2",i) == 50,1,0) 

}
```

The input df could be:

```
df<- as.data.frame(cbind(c(50,100,40),c(50,0,60),c(100,0,50), c(0,50,50)))
colnames(df) <- c("parcj_immo1","parpr_immo1","parcj_immo2","parpr_immo2")
```

And the output desired:

```
df_final <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(50,100,40),c(50,0,60),c(100,0,50), c(0,50,50), c(1,0,0),c(0,0,1)))
colnames(df_final) <- c("parcj_immo1","parpr_immo1","parcj_immo2","parpr_immo2","immo_com1","immo_com2")
```

The condition for immo_com_'i' to be equal to one is that parcj_immo'i' == parpr_immo'i' and parpr_immo'i' != 0

I know it's bad to use ifelse and also loops, that's why I'm wondering what kind of command I can use to avoid their utilisation.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you post an example of `df`  and an expected output?

Comment: Do you *have* to use `dplyr`, or are you open to other solutions?

Comment: I added an exemple of df and expected output !

Comment: I do not have to use dplyr, but I'm used to code with this package so I wanted to preserve a certain homogeneity

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this, with some renaming at the end?

```
library(dplyr)
df |>
  mutate(across(starts_with("parcj"), ~1*(.==50), .names = "is50_{.col}")) |>
  rename_with(stringr::str_replace, 
              pattern = "is50_parcj_immo", 
              replacement = "immo_com")
```

Result

```
  parcj_immo1 parpr_immo1 parcj_immo2 parpr_immo2 immo_com1 immo_com2
1          50          50         100           0         1         0
2         100           0           0          50         0         0
3          40          60          50          50         0         1
```